# Why is the DEBUG trap executed more times than expected?

Tags: bash

The following code triggers the debug trap 3 times. I am however expecting only 2 executions - one for `foo`, the second for `echo hello`:

```
foo() {
    echo hello
}

set -T
trap 'echo oops' DEBUG
foo
```

**Output:**

```
oops
oops
oops
hello
```

**Expected output:**

```
oops
oops
hello
```

---

**`Bash` versions tested:**

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
GNU bash, version 5.0.0(1)-alpha (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

I am pretty sure I just misunderstood the manual and that I am missing something really simple/obvious here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr: Bash runs the debug trap one extra time when invoking a function to allow breaking on the function itself rather than its first command. Here's from the source code's [execute_function](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c?id=64447609994bfddeef1061948022c074093e9a9f#n4783) used to invoke a bash function:

```c
  /* Run the debug trap here so we can trap at the start of a function's
     execution rather than the execution of the body's first command. */
```

---

### Source diving time

[Here is the code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/trap.c?id=64447609994bfddeef1061948022c074093e9a9f#n1081) that executes debug traps:

```c
int run_debug_trap () {
/* (...) */
    trap_exit_value = _run_trap_internal (DEBUG_TRAP, "debug trap");
```

I put a breakpoint on that line, `trap.c:1081` as of today, and had a look at the backtraces:

#### First instance

```
Breakpoint 1, run_debug_trap () at trap.c:1081
1081          trap_exit_value = _run_trap_internal (DEBUG_TRAP, "debug trap");
(gdb) where
#0  run_debug_trap () at trap.c:1081
#1  0x000055555559fd3d in execute_simple_command (simple_command=0x5555558aacc8, pipe_in=-1, pipe_out=-1, async=0, fds_to_close=0x555555899148) at execute_cmd.c:4056
#2  0x0000555555599fd7 in execute_command_internal (command=0x5555558aae08, asynchronous=0, pipe_in=-1, pipe_out=-1, fds_to_close=0x555555899148) at execute_cmd.c:807
#3  0x00005555555995c1 in execute_command (command=0x5555558aae08) at execute_cmd.c:405
#4  0x0000555555583c9e in reader_loop () at eval.c:180
#5  0x0000555555581794 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe4d8, env=0x7fffffffe4f0) at shell.c:792
(gdb) up
#1  0x000055555559fd3d in execute_simple_command (simple_command=0x5555558aacc8, pipe_in=-1, pipe_out=-1, async=0, fds_to_close=0x555555899148) at execute_cmd.c:4056
4056      result = run_debug_trap ();

(gdb) print *simple_command->words->word
$3 = {word = 0x5555558a5268 "foo", flags = 0}
```

In other words, this is the simple command `foo`. So far so good.

#### Second instance

```
Breakpoint 1, run_debug_trap () at trap.c:1081
1081          trap_exit_value = _run_trap_internal (DEBUG_TRAP, "debug trap");
(gdb) where
#0  run_debug_trap () at trap.c:1081
#1  0x00005555555a170a in execute_function (var=0x5555558ab648, words=0x5555558aac28, flags=0, fds_to_close=0x555555899148, async=0, subshell=0) at execute_cmd.c:4787
#2  0x00005555555a1c68 in execute_builtin_or_function (words=0x5555558aac28, builtin=0x0, var=0x5555558ab648, redirects=0x0, fds_to_close=0x555555899148, flags=0) at execute_cmd.c:5030
#3  0x00005555555a0660 in execute_simple_command (simple_command=0x5555558aacc8, pipe_in=-1, pipe_out=-1, async=0, fds_to_close=0x555555899148) at execute_cmd.c:4330
#4  0x0000555555599fd7 in execute_command_internal (command=0x5555558aae08, asynchronous=0, pipe_in=-1, pipe_out=-1, fds_to_close=0x555555899148) at execute_cmd.c:807
#5  0x00005555555995c1 in execute_command (command=0x5555558aae08) at execute_cmd.c:405
#6  0x0000555555583c9e in reader_loop () at eval.c:180
#7  0x0000555555581794 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe4d8, env=0x7fffffffe4f0) at shell.c:792
```

This is more interesting. We're still executing the simple command `foo` from before, but it's triggering again! Why though? Let's have a look at the call site, [execute_cmd.c:4787](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c?id=64447609994bfddeef1061948022c074093e9a9f#n4783):

```c
  /* Run the debug trap here so we can trap at the start of a function's
     execution rather than the execution of the body's first command. */
  showing_function_line = 1;
  save_current = currently_executing_command;
  result = run_debug_trap ();
```

In other words, Bash appears to intentionally run the debug trap one additional time for the purpose of breaking on a function rather than its first command.

#### Third instance

Is unsurprisingly the function's `echo` command, so I won't include it.

Comment: Very nice! I am impressed by the level of research you must have put into this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you understand that `DEBUG` trap enables running the command defined within its definition ( `trap 'action' signal`) before every other shell command and `set -T` enables the trap to all sub-shells and functions also. So once you set the `trap` you have three executions happening.

1. Call to the function `foo`, before which once the `trap` is fired resulting in first instance of the printing the string.
2. And then you have an `echo oops` command inside the `trap` definition where is `echo` is just *another* command, so before running it the `trap` is fired.
3. And the actual `echo` command in the `trap` producing the 3rd instance
4. And `hello` follows last after the complete `trap` execution is complete.

See the sequence when ran from the debug mode

```
$ bash -x script.sh
+ set -T
+ trap 'echo oops' DEBUG
++ echo oops                # <--- triggered by call to 'foo'
oops
+ foo
++ echo oops                # <--- triggered by call to 'echo oops' inside trap definition
oops
++ echo oops                # <--- result of the actual command to be run
oops
+ echo hello                # <--- result of the function call 'foo'
hello
```

Adding in more explanation to explain the sequence, imagine the `DEBUG` trap is fired *before* any shell function/commands are run. Let's breakdown it to the following. Understand that are two instructions/commands and two resulting actions for those commands

1. Call to `foo` is the first instruction, so a trap is fired and action `echo oops` is to be run now. Remember here `foo` is the trigger and `echo oops` is the *action* and we see it once for the first time.
2. Now the second instruction is the `echo oops` which *triggers* another action, so because of the `trap`, the `echo oops` is fired and then the actual instruction is done which also happens to do `echo oops`.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I understand fully. So...the command inside the `trap` also triggers the `trap` again, correct? So how come it doesn't result in an infinite call loop? Or I would at least expect **each** `echo oops` triggering the `trap` once resulting in 4 `oops` :/ As it is now, only one `echo oops` triggers the trap. How is that possible?

Comment: @mickp: That is not the case, there is one command inside `trap` definition i.e. an `echo`, a trap is fired for that alone and the actual command is run. There is no reason for an infinite loop, the trap is run for commands and _not_ for command outputs

Comment: The way I understand it now: 1) `foo` triggers `echo oops` 2) that `echo oops` should trigger the `trap` again and execute one extra `echo oops` = we have 2 `echo oops` now 3) the exact same thing goes for `echo hello` = we have 4 `echo oops`. What I don't understand is, why the `trap` is triggered only by one call to `echo oops` and not by both :(

Comment: I don't follow the explanation for why this theory wouldn't lead the infinite recursion either, but it can alternatively be disproven by the fact that `trap 'echo oops; true; true;' DEBUG` does not print `oops` more times.