# Prompt command, but for shell scripts

Tags: bash

I want a $(thing/command/variable) like PROMPT_COMMAND, but for a nonintervention shell script that runs a command every line $(in the same Bash instance). For example,

Normal

```
echo hel
echo hel
echo hel
echo hel
```

After thing

```
thingcom "sleep 1" # Note this would act as if this was the case

echo hel
sleep 1
echo hel
sleep 1
echo hel
sleep 1
echo hel
sleep 1
```

Comment: See in particular the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45123073/14122 on the linked duplicate, suggesting use of a DEBUG trap.

Comment: non interactave shell script

Comment: @lnee_94, if the linked duplicate doesn't address your question, please edit to describe why and how it fails to do so.

Comment: (DEBUG traps _do_ have caveats, but we have other Q&A entries -- such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51557238/why-is-the-debug-trap-executed-more-times-than-expected -- describing them).